# "there are too many records to complete this operation" error in calculated item in pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table, calculated-field

Does anyone know how to solve this error in excel?
I have created a pivot having as actual source a big amount of data (around 500000 rows). The pivot contains a calculated item but when I try to refresh it I get this error.
The error disappears when I go to solve order and I remove the calculated item, but I really need in on the report. Any idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What calculation are you doing? Have you tried to do this calculation manually first? maybe in some lines the calculation is returning an error.

Comment: Calculate the item for each row then add it to the source data as a value then create the pivot.